# Como registro os dados de um formulário no banco de dados em Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estou com um pequeno problema na produção de um sistema de registro, está tudo funcionando bem, mas quando vou verificar no banco de dados nenhum dado submetido no formulário aparece, ou seja não está registrado.

***Classe no Controller:***

```
public function Submit(Request $request)
{
    Model::create($request ->all());
    return redirect()->action('MainController@index');
}
```

***Observação:*** não vou por a `View` porque ela é muito grande (***tem umas 150 linhas de código, só o formulário, mas se for necessário eu ponho.***)

***Sua respectiva model:***

```
class Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = array('nome',
        'CPF',
        'email',
        'datnasc',
        'naturalidade',
        'turno',
        'uf_natural',
        'nome_mae',
        'nome_pai',
        'nome_resp',
        'cpf_resp',
        'rua',
        'numero',
        'bairro',
        'complemento',
        'cep',
        'didade',
        'estado',
        'tel_celular',
        'tel_fixo',
        'tipo_escola',
        'escola_origem',
        'serie');

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Dá um dd($request ->all()); antes de Model::create($request ->all()); e p verifica se os dados estão sendo submetidos. Verifique também a action do form

Comment: Os nomes dos campos do formulário são iguais aos do banco de dados que foram preenchidos na variável `$fillable` ?

Comment: Está assim mesmo: `class Model extends Model` se tiver é um prática ruim porque Model já está reservado pelo Eloquent definir suas classes, então não faça nenhuma classe com o nome de `Model`? Na sua View você poderia colocar somente a parte do `<form></form>` e as suas rotas também!

Comment: Não está não, é somente um nome genérico.

Consegui resolver meu problema com os comentários acima, Obrigado a todos!